# Problems while printing numbers in Python

Tags: python, loops, printing, primes

I'm making a program that prints all the prime numbers from a number that the user enters. Everything is working but I'm just having trouble printing the numbers.

```
def math(user):
  for num in range (user + 1):
    if num > 1:
      for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          break
      else:
        print('The Primes from 2 to ', user, 'are: ',num)


def main():
  user = ('Enter the maximum value to check primes up to: ')
  math(user)
```

When I enter `10` it prints:

```
Enter the maximum value to check primes up to: 10
The Primes from 2 to  10 are:  2
The Primes from 2 to  10 are:  3
The Primes from 2 to  10 are:  5
The Primes from 2 to  10 are:  7
```

I just want to have:

```
Enter the maximum value to check primes up to: 10
The Primes from 2 to  10 are:  2, 3, 5, 7
```

I think I have to add a list but I'm not sure where.

Comment: You should print the header `The Primes from 2 to ', user, 'are:` _before_ the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the [duplicate] answer will help much OP until they first get to the proper logical steps to reach the [duplicate] question.

A bit like suggested, you could print the beginning of your answer first (or store as a string) and then calculate your list of result and concatenate the whole things at the end for printing.
If you store a string, you could add to it each found result, and print at the end. But the problem is managing the number of comma, as I guess you want one less comma than result values.

The pythonic solution to the 'comma problem' is the [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function. The notation is unusual, just remember the string you are 'working with' is your 'separator' string, in our case the comma (followed by a space for good measure). Like this:

```
', '.join(iterables_of_strings)
```

The usual way to use it is to store all your result (in str form) in a iterable, typically a list, like this:

```
def math(user):
  result = []
  for num in range (user + 1):
    if num > 1:
      for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          break
      else:
        result.append(str(num))
```

and to format all elements of your list at the end with the join function:

```
  print('The Primes from 2 to ', user, 'are: ', ', '.join(result) )
```